# EF Core 5 - Does the order of Include()/Where() methods in queries matter?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I am upgrading from .NET Core 2.2 to .NET 5.0 one major release at a time (2.2 -> 3.0 -> 3.1 -> 5.0), and I have a LINQ query into a MySQL database that works differently after the upgrade to 5.0. The query works fine in 2.2, 3.0, and 3.1, but after the upgrade to 5.0 one of the `Include()` calls does not seem to have any effect. The query is:

```
var adminClient = (this._context.AdminUserClients
    .Include(f => f.Client)
    .Where(f => f.User.Id == user.Id && f.Client.Id != 1)
    .Include(f => f.Client.ClientUserRoles)  // This Include does not seem to have an effect
    .ThenInclude(f => f.User)
    .FirstOrDefault())?.Client;
```

(See below for the model.)

When this runs in EF Core 3.1 (2.2 and 3.0 are similar) it generates a SQL statement with two subqueries, one to join `AdminUserClients`, `AspNetUsers`, and `Clients`, and one to join `ClientUserRoles` and `AspNetUsers`. Then, it joins the two subqueries to generate the result. In EF Core 5.0, the generated SQL statement does not reference `ClientUserRoles`--it is essentially just the first subquery in the 3.1 SQL statement.

If I modify the query to move the `Where()` call after the `Include()` calls, it works:

```
var adminClient = (this._context.AdminUserClients
    .Include(f => f.Client)
    .Include(f => f.Client.ClientUserRoles)  // This Include runs fine
    .ThenInclude(f => f.User)
    .Where(f => f.User.Id == user.Id && f.Client.Id != 1)
    .FirstOrDefault())?.Client;
```

In this case, the generated SQL statement is virtually identical to the one generated in 3.1.

I am not sure why this makes a difference. Maybe the `User` object needs to be included before it is referenced in the `Where()` method? But that doesn't make sense to me because (1) it works in 2.2, 3.0, and 3.1, and (2) my understanding is that the <strike>order of the methods</strike> relative order of the `Include()` and `Where()` methods should not impact the return set (though I get that it can impact performance).

#### Questions

1. Is there a problem with the ordering of the `Include()` and `Where()` methods in the original query?
2. Is there a change from EF Core 3.1 to EF Core 5.0 that would cause the behavior of this query to change?

#### Note on Split Queries

Because I am upgrading from 2.2 to 5.0, I am using `UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery)` to emulate the 2.2 behavior. However, I have tested:

1. Adding `AsSplitQuery()` to the query.
2. Using `UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SingleQuery)`.
3. Removing `UseQuerySplittingBehavior()` entirely.
   In all of these cases, the behavior is the same.

#### Model

```
public class AdminUserClient
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public UserNotificationsSetting NotificationSetting { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public ClientUserRole ClientUserRole { get; set; }
    public bool Locked { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool RequireTwoFactor { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public ICollection<ClientUserRole> ClientUserRoles { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public bool Locked { get; set; }
}

public class ClientUserRole
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public long ClientId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(15)")]
    public UserRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

### Update

This has been confirmed as an EF Core 5.0 bug from one of the contributors: see https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24953.

Comment: @Magnetron Good point. I should have been clearer--I was referring specifically to the order of the `Include()` and `Where()` methods relative to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition (design), the relative order of `Include` with other LINQ query operators should not matter - the only requirement is `Include` to be for the entity which starts the query.

So no *intentional* changes in that regard between the aforementioned EF Core versions. However, definition/design is one story, implementation is another. Simply said, you are hitting EF Core 5.x bug, so it would be good to report it to their GitHub issue tracker.

The problem does not appear always, and seems to be related to the expression used in the `Where` predicate (in general `Include` should not affect usage of of the navigation properties in filters, ordering etc. LINQ operators), and more specifically the navigation property `Client` here

```
f.Client.Id != 1
```

in combination with

```
.Include(f => f.Client)
```

If you remove that condition from `Where`, or move the `Include` after the `Where` having that condition, the rest of includes work. While with this combination they don't.

So report it in order to let them know it and eventually fix it. Until then, since you can't remove the criteria (apparently), reorder the `Includes`.

And if you want to be safe (and nor hitting similar unexpected bugs), even though it's not required by definition, put all the `Includes` at the beginning of the query, right after the `DbSet`, and then all other operators.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I opened https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24953 and will update this question with any feedback from that ticket.

Comment: This has been confirmed as a bug by one of the EF Core contributors.